# understanding matrix multiplication during diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand the transformation being done during the step in diagonalization theorem.

Let $A$ be a diagonizable matrix, such that $A=PCP^{-1}$. Let $B=\{b_1,b_2...,b_n\}$ and $P=[b_1,b_2,...., b_n]$. The factorization is explained to some amount as follows:

$1)\vec x \rightarrow (2)[x]_B \rightarrow (3)[A\vec x]_B \rightarrow(4)A\vec x$

- left multiplying 1) by $P^{-1}$ gives (2)
- multiplying (2) by C gives (3)  ###THIS IS WHAT I DON'T GET----
- multiplying (3) by $P$ gives (4)

I don't understand how you get (3) multiplying (2) by C?

Answer (score 1):

It's an elementary question about the change of basis: let $f\in L(E)$ where $E$ is a vector space of dimension $n$. Let $A$ (resp. $C$) be the matrix of $f$ when we choose $(e_i)$ (resp. $(f_i)$)  as a basis of $E$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. If $P=[p_{i,j}]$ is the matrix of change of basis $(e_i)\rightarrow (f_i)$, then $C=P^{-1}AP$, that is, $A=PCP^{-1}$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. i) The key of the proof is: let $x\in E$, and let $X=[x_i]$ (resp. $X'=[x'_i]$) be its column matrix wrt. $(e_i)$ (resp. $(f_i)$). Then $X=PX'$, that is $X'=P^{-1}X$.

Indeed, $x=\sum_i x'_if_i=\sum_i(x'_i\sum_j p_{j,i}e_j)=\sum_j(\sum_i p_{j,i}x'_i)e_j$, that is $x_j=\sum_i p_{j,i}x'_i$.

ii) Let $Y=AX$ and, with the above notation: $Y'=CX'$. Then $Y=PY'=PCX'=PCP^{-1}X$, that is, $A=PCP^{-1}$. $\square$

If you decompose the last equality: $X\rightarrow P^{-1}X=X'\rightarrow CX'=Y'\rightarrow PY'=Y$.

In particular, the second arrow is the action of $f$ on the basis $(f_i)$, which is represented by the matrix $C$.